# How to add image as title in UIalertController?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS, I included image as title and message, both are displaying but message not properly populate. How to set message exactly below of title image, I tried but not happening. Please can anyone help me?

called in func:

```
CommonMethods.alertWithImage(msg:"Allow XXX to access your device's location?", 
                             Icon: UIImage(named: "loc.png")!,
                             fromView: self)
```

Here is my code:

```
    let alrt = UIAlertController(title:nil, message: msg, preferredStyle:.actionSheet)
    
    alrt.setMessage(font: UIFont(name: "Poppins-medium", size: 20), color: UIColor.white)
    
    let btn1 = UIAlertAction(title: "While using the app.", style: .default,handler: nil)
    let btn2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Only this time.", style: .default,handler: nil)
    let btn3 = UIAlertAction(title: "Deny", style: .default,handler: nil)
  
    alrt.addAction(btn1)
    alrt.addAction(btn2)
    alrt.addAction(btn3)
   
    alrt.view.tintColor = UIColor.blue
    let subview = (alrt.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews.first!)! as UIView
    alrt.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 180, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35))
    
        imageView.image = Icon
        alrt.view.addSubview(imageView)
    fromView.present(alrt, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Why are you even showing this dialog?  You should request location access and then ios will show the permission dialog.

Comment: You shouldn't customize `UIAlertController`, but instead use a custom one (either yours, or using a third party lib). Why? Because it's not recommended, and view hierarchy might change in future as said by the doc.

Comment: Please can you explain me by screenshot@Paulw11

Comment: Did you read Apple documentation about CoreLocation ? You can also find lot of tutorials on web on how to configure your info.plist file and asking/checking for user permission.

Answer (score 1):

as @Larme said, you can use a custom one (  a third party lib ).

Here is the solution of customize `UIAlertController`

```
class Alert: UIAlertController{
    
    
    let offset: CGFloat = 20
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        if let title = getLabel(for: view){
            var f = title.frame
            f.origin = CGPoint(x: f.origin.x, y: f.origin.y - offset)
            title.frame = f
        }
    }
    
    
    
    func getLabel(for v: UIView?) -> UILabel?{
        guard let vue = v else{ return nil }
        var result: UILabel?
        for sub in vue.subviews{
            sub.clipsToBounds = false
            if sub.isKind(of: UILabel.self){
                return sub as? UILabel
            }
            else {
                result = getLabel(for: sub)
                if result != nil{
                    return result
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

use like this:

```
 let alrt = Alert(title:nil, message: msg, preferredStyle:.actionSheet)
```

Comment: Thank you so much@dengST30, it's helped me lot

Answer (score 0):

This is the way how i can archived my goal. You also can try this

**Create your UIAlertController**

```
let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
```

**Create image what you want to show instead of your a your UIAlertController title**

```
 let barIconImageView: UIImageView = {
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "ic_bar")
            return imageView
        }()
        actionSheet.view.addSubview(barIconImageView)
```

**[image: Set the image position in the UIAlertController]**

```
 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            barIconImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  actionSheet.view.topAnchor, constant: 12),
            barIconImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: actionSheet.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            barIconImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: actionSheet.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20)
        ])
```